# Gradle run task not working - Error: --module-path requires module path specification

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to run my Gradle project from the command line using `gradle run`. I've done this in the past, and it was as simple as adding the `application` plugin and specifying the `mainClassName`. However, this time, it just won't work.

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    
    // BEGIN CUSTOM DEPENDENCIES //
    
    // jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin
    compile group: 'com.zenjava', name: 'javafx-maven-plugin', version: '8.8.3'
    
    
    // Spark - used for the server
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3"
    
    // slf4j-simple, used for server output
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.30'
    
    // slf4j-api, used for server output
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'
    
    // org.json, used to send data to the front end
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20200518'
    
    // java-string-similarity, used to calculate Levenshtein distance to sort results
    compile group: 'info.debatty', name: 'java-string-similarity', version: '2.0.0'
    
    
}

javafx {
    version = '11'
    modules = [ 'javafx.base', 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.swing', 'javafx.graphics', 'javafx.media', 'javafx.web' ]
    configuration = 'compileOnly'
}

mainClassName = 'io.gitlab.hasanger.searchengine.SearchEngineServer'
```

And here's the error I get:

```
$ gradle run

> Configure project :
Project : => no module-info.java found

> Task :run FAILED
Error: --module-path requires module path specification

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

The error seems to imply that I need to create `module-info.java`. But if I create `module-info.java`, I'll need to specify every single dependency my project has. I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing, but I can't figure out what.

I'm using Gradle 6.7 and Java 11. Output of `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Output of `gradle -version`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-10-14 16:13:12 UTC
Revision:     312ba9e0f4f8a02d01854d1ed743b79ed996dfd3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          11.0.8 (Ubuntu 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-48-generic amd64
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: org.gradle.warning.mode=all     add this line into your gradle.properties file and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I couldn't find a `gradle.properties` file in my project. Instead, I tried `gradle run --warning-mode=all`, and it gave me this new information: `The compile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the implementation or api configuration instead.` Since it's only deprecated, this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I had to remove the `configuration = 'compileOnly'` line from my `build.gradle`. This is what the final `build.gradle` looks like:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    
    // BEGIN CUSTOM DEPENDENCIES //
    
    // jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin
    compile group: 'com.zenjava', name: 'javafx-maven-plugin', version: '8.8.3'
    
    // Spark - used for the server
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3"
    
    // slf4j-simple, used for server output
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.30'
    
    // slf4j-api, used for server output
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'
    
    // org.json, used to send data to the front end
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20200518'
    
    // java-string-similarity, used to calculate Levenshtein distance to sort results
    compile group: 'info.debatty', name: 'java-string-similarity', version: '2.0.0'
    
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.base', 'javafx.swing', 'javafx.web' ]
}

mainClassName = 'io.gitlab.hasanger.searchengine.SearchEngineServer'
```

I'm not sure why I decided to include that line in the first place. The [JavaFX plugin page](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin) mentions that if this line is added, it won't include native binaries.